# Project with multiple variables

Tags: matlab, variables, structure

I would like to know how you handle the declaration of variables in matlab when you have multiple variables. Do you create a separate .m file containing the variables? Do you put them in a structure? What is the best practice?

Comment: You don't need to declare variables - just use them. If you want to document what they stand for, you could consider writing a header of sorts. Do you mean you have constants?

Comment: You might take a look at [this earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19361240/1967396) about using a `classdef` as a way to store constants cleanly.

Comment: How are you going to use the variables that are to be stored?

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin Mostly going to use them from the base workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few scenarios I can think of, the lower numbers may be more efficient, but the highest numbers are expected to be the safest:

**1. You have a lot of variables, and sometimes need all of them**

*Suggested solution*: save in mat file

When you need one, just execute a short command to load all of them

**2. You have a lot of variables, and often need just a few of them**

*Suggested solution*: save in mat file, database, textfile or basically anywhere

When you need one, just execute a short command to load only the relevant variables in

**3. You have a lot of variables, and often need many of them**

*Suggested solution*: combine into struct and save in mat file

As you only load in the struct, you minimize the risk of overwriting an existing variable. Just make sure to familzarize yourself with the struct name and rememer not to use it for other things. Each time you need to use a variable you will of course be required to add the structname as prefix.

**4. You have some variables, and often need very many of them**

*Suggested solution*: Create a function (or class) for them

If you make sure this is on your default path, this is the safest way. If a variable exists it will use the variable, otherwise it will try to execute your trivial function.

Note that you can declare numerous functions in one M file.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have some constants you use in many different scripts / functions that you don't want to give as input to the function (too many, and they're constant).

I suggest you have it in a separate m-file that you call when you run your functions. Either as:

```
%% Initialize variables:
import_vars;
```

or

```
%% Initialize variables from function:
[a, b, c, d] = import_vars();
```

In the latter you can give different names to the variables when used in different functions. This way you reduce the risk of overwriting variables (thanks Floris).

The latter one is frequenctly used in a program I've been using earlier.

Comment: The former method runs a great risk of overwriting variables in the program you are using - at least with the function you control the name of the variables inside the program that uses them. I really prefer the class constants method (see [my earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19361240/1967396) - a bit more wordy, but ensures that you know exactly what the variable is and where it came from (where it was defined). One minute longer when writing, one day less debugging.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly use a `struct` to keep your variables organized and have compact initialization. But if you want to retain loose variables, and you are just looking for a super compact way of initializing variables, have a look at [`deal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html).  Here's a contrived example to demonstrate its versatility:

```
>> [A,B,C,D,E] = deal(2,'x',struct([]),[],rand(2),{'str',123})
A =
     2
B =
x
C = 
0x0 struct array with no fields.
D =
     []
E =
    0.8147    0.1270
    0.9058    0.9134
F = 
    'str'    [123]
>>
```

Obviously, readability suffers considerably, but you can have any number of in/out arguments and they can be any data type.